# Find the derivative of a function containing radicals

Tags: derivatives

**Find the derivative of a function containing radicals**

Let $f(x)= -7x^5 \sqrt x - \dfrac{8}{x^2 \sqrt x}$

$f'(x)=?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
f(x)=-7x^{5+1/2}-8x^{-2-1/2}
$$ then use
$$
\left(x^\alpha \right)'=\alpha \cdot x^{\alpha-1}, \qquad (u+v)'=u'+v'.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

f(x) = $-7x^5 \cdot x^{\frac12} - 8x^{-2} \cdot x^{\frac{-1}2}$

= $-7x^{5+\frac12} - 8x^{-2-\frac12}$

= $-7x^{\frac{11}2} - 8x^{\frac{-5}2}$

Now find derivative.